# Rated current vs peak current in connector

Tags: current, connector

I'm looking at panel connectors and I'm not sure about the current capacity. One connector is rated at 25A continuous, which is above what I expect my device to be driving, but during startup, peak current gets to 30.8A. The specifications on the connector say nothing about peak current so how do I know if I can use this connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on how long peak current is applied.

If you are starting some large load and it takes a minute or two to wind up, you probably need a bigger connector or to double up pins.

If it's a few milliseconds, you will be good to go.

Anywhere in the middle... is a grey area.

Definitely do not use the connector if it is a HOT connect though. I mean do not expect it to survive long as a switch.